# Is there a way to load a static class without an object?

Tags: java, class, static, loader

I have a static class with a static map that I need loaded. I'll get an error and when I debug it, I get `SomeClass.someMap` class is not loaded." I get that I could create an object of the class, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having it static, doesn't it?

I barely read about ClassLoader, is this something I should use? Or maybe create an own "class loader" which will instantiate the class and other static classes at launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force the class's static initializer to run without creating an instance, you need to initialize the class with `Class.forName("somepackage.SomeClass");` -- see the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I see, so if I understood forName right, just writing `Class.forName("GameReader");` will do? No need for `Class t = Class.forName("GameReader");`?

Comment: Correct. Make sure you give it the fully-qualified name (including the package).